# when does the following system has infinite solutions

Tags: linear-algebra, systems-of-equations, determinant

I was trying to solve the following exercise but I couldn't get anywhere:

Find the values of a and b for which the following system has infinite solutions:

$2x+3y-z=a$

$3x-by+z=1$

$ax-y-z=2$

I tried to solve the problem using the determinant, I mean we know that $Ax=b$ has infinite solutions if $|A|=0$ but at the end I get an expression that I'm not able to reduce.

I would really appreciate any help or advice you could give me.

Many thanks

Comment: Determinant zero gives you that the existence of one solution implies the existence of infinte solutions. But determinant zero alone is not sufficient for the existence of a solution

Comment: What expression did you get?

Comment: So how can I prove that there are no solution or in this case there exist solutions?

Comment: I got that 2b -2ab + 3a +17 =|A|

Comment: You shouldn't say "infinite solutions" if you mean "infinitely many solutions".  If there were just two solutions, and each one of those is an "infinite solution" (whatever that might mean), then there would be infinite solutions, but not infinitely many solutions. $\qquad$

Answer (score 2):

**Idea**

Write $$A=\begin{pmatrix} 2 & 3 & -1 \\ 3 & -b & 1 \\ a & -1 & -1\end{pmatrix}, B=\begin{pmatrix} 2 & 3 & -1 & a \\ 3 & -b & 1 & 1 \\ a & -1 & -1 & 2\end{pmatrix}.$$

The system has infinitely many solutions if and only if $ran(A)=ran(B)<3.$ Since $A$ has a 2-order minor that non vanishes, $$A=\begin{pmatrix} \color{red}{2} & 3 & \color{red} {-1} \\ \color{red}{3} & -b & \color{red}{1} \\ a & -1 & -1\end{pmatrix},\begin{vmatrix}2 & -1 \\ 3 & 1\end{vmatrix}\ne 0,$$ the only posibility is $ran(A)=ran(B)=2.$ So, that happens if and only if

$$\begin{vmatrix} 2 & 3 & -1 \\ 3 & -b & 1 \\ a & -1 & -1\end{vmatrix}=\begin{vmatrix} 2  & -1 & a \\ 3  & 1 & 1 \\ a  & -1 & 2\end{vmatrix}=0.$$
I hope you can finish.

Comment: What does "2-order minor that non vanishes" means?

Comment: @gbox a minor of order 2 different from zero.

Comment: Sorry @mfl I didn't get why A has a 2-order minor that non vanish.

Comment: @Michael Can you see it in red?

Comment: @mfl of course haha sorry. Thank you so much for the help.